# Quartz Frequency c#

Tags: c#, cron, quartz, crontrigger

I want to get the frequencies of my scheduler when it will be triggered for a day. I've set the ticking interval using cron expression, but is there something using which I will have a list of frequencies when my Scheduler will trigger.

```
IScheduler placeOrderScheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
            placeOrderScheduler.Start();
            PlaceOrderJob placeOrderJob = new PlaceOrderJob();
            var TickInterval = placeOrderJob.GetTickInterval();
            if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(TickInterval)))
            {
                //var schedule = CrontabSchedule.Parse(TickInterval);
                //var ime =  schedule.GetNextOccurrence(DateTime.Now);
                string JobName = "PlaceOrderJob";
                var placeOrderjob = JobBuilder.Create<PlaceOrderService.PlaceOrderJob>().WithIdentity(JobName, "PlaceOrderJob")
                                                   .Build();
                var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithCronSchedule(TickInterval).Build();
                if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(TimeZoneConfigID)))
                    ((Quartz.Impl.Triggers.CronTriggerImpl)trigger).TimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimeZoneConfigID);}
```

Comment: The TickInterval which I've assigned above is "0 0/2 * 1/1 * ? *". I want to get the list of time intervals when my scheduler will be triggered. "PlaceOrderService.PlaceOrderJob" is my windows scheduler which has implementation of the Exectue method IJobExecutionContext.

Comment: Can anyone please help me or throw some light as of how i can achieve this?